# How can I fix this perl script that parses linux smaps?

Tags: linux, perl, memory

I found [this perl script that parses linux smaps](http://bmaurer.blogspot.com/2006/03/memory-usage-with-smaps.html), but it seems a bit out of date:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Copyright Ben Maurer
# you can distribute this under the MIT/X11 License

use Linux::Smaps;

my $pid=shift @ARGV;
unless ($pid) {
        print "./smem.pl <pid>\n";
        exit 1;
}
my $map=Linux::Smaps->new($pid);
my @VMAs = $map->vmas;

format STDOUT =
VMSIZE:  @######## kb
$map->size
RSS:     @######## kb total
$map->rss
         @######## kb shared
$map->shared_clean + $map->shared_dirty
         @######## kb private clean
$map->private_clean
         @######## kb private dirty
$map->private_dirty
.

write;

printPrivateMappings ();
printSharedMappings ();

sub sharedMappings () {
    return grep { ($_->shared_clean  + $_->shared_dirty) > 0 } @VMAs;
}

sub privateMappings () {
    return grep { ($_->private_clean  + $_->private_dirty) > 0 } @VMAs;
}

sub printPrivateMappings ()
{
    $TYPE = "PRIVATE MAPPINGS";
    $^ = 'SECTION_HEADER';
    $~ = 'SECTION_ITEM';
    $- = 0;
    $= = 100000000;
    foreach  $vma (sort {-($a->private_dirty <=> $b->private_dirty)}
                                   privateMappings ()) {
        $size  = $vma->size;
        $dirty = $vma->private_dirty;
        $clean = $vma->private_clean;
        $file  = $vma->file_name;
        write;
    }
}

sub printSharedMappings ()
{
    $TYPE = "SHARED MAPPINGS";
    $^ = 'SECTION_HEADER';
    $~ = 'SECTION_ITEM';
    $- = 0;
    $= = 100000000;

    foreach  $vma (sort {-(($a->shared_clean + $a->shared_dirty)
                           <=>
                           ($b->shared_clean + $b->shared_dirty))}
                   sharedMappings ()) {

        $size  = $vma->size;
        $dirty = $vma->shared_dirty;
        $clean = $vma->shared_clean;
        $file  = $vma->file_name;
        write;


    }
}

format SECTION_HEADER =
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$TYPE
@>>>>>>>>>> @>>>>>>>>>>  @>>>>>>>>>   @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
"vmsize" "rss clean" "rss dirty" "file"
.

format SECTION_ITEM =
@####### kb @####### kb @####### kb   @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$size $clean $dirty $file
.
```

When I run the script I get:

```
./smem.perl 121212
Use of comma-less variable list is deprecated at ./smem.perl line 86.
Use of comma-less variable list is deprecated at ./smem.perl line 86.
Use of comma-less variable list is deprecated at ./smem.perl line 86.
Use of comma-less variable list is deprecated at ./smem.perl line 91.
Use of comma-less variable list is deprecated at ./smem.perl line 91.
Use of comma-less variable list is deprecated at ./smem.perl line 91.
Can't locate object method "size" via package "Linux::Smaps" at ./smem.perl line 18.
```

I'm running perl 5 and the latest version of Linux::Smaps.  I'm not a perl guy, but I'm wondering if this is an easy fix.  Also if you know of a similar utility I'd love to hear about that, too.

Comment: Try adding commas between the strings in the fourth line of the first format ("vmsize", "rss clean", "rss dirty", "file"), and between the variables in the second format ($size, $clean, $dirty, $file).

Comment: Thank you, that clears up the warnings!

Answer (score 1):

The module's source has a comment that reveals what's going on:

```
It creates accessor methods dynamically depending on what the kernel reveals.
```

What that tells me is that even though you may have instantiated the object correctly, the accessor method `size` hasn't been dynamically created yet.  That could be a result of the kernel not "revealing" everything needed to fully populate the object.

The format deprecation messages are non-fatal, but trying to invoke an object method from a module when the method hasn't been created yet is.

As for the deprecation messages, see [Why isn't my Perl format working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1253134/716443)